# Sci-fi book featuring robot dogs in the jungle

Tags: story-identification

I am searching for a book that I read a long time ago.

It is set in a world with two societies, one living in sealed, high-tech cities, and one living a primitive lifestyle in the jungle or forest - they are all human though.

Occasionally the two sides meet to trade but it is the city-dwellers who have the power, which they maintain through robot dogs patrolling outside.

The inner workings of these dogs are exposed (they are not disguised as real dogs).

One character (the protagonist, I think) finds a screwdriver and takes it to an elder in his village and asks him whether it could be used as a weapon against the dogs. The old man laughs and says that the dog would kill him before he even got the first screw out. The young man then asks what a screw is. So the old man was either privy to some handed-down knowledge, or remembers the world before the split into the two factions.

Are there any ideas what this book could be?

Comment: Sound's a lot like "Deathworld" by Harry Harrison, but I don't remember robot dogs or the screwdriver.

Comment: Definitely not Deathworld, but thanks

Comment: Sounds a little like something Lucius Shepard or Dave Wolverton might have written. Was it set in South America?

Comment: Have you checked out [this list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_robotic_dogs#In_fiction) to see if the book you're looking for is on there?

Comment: Good suggestion, but nothing on that rings a bell

Comment: I don't know its name, I'm sorry, but it sounds as if this might be the story on which a filk song (SF-based folk song) I learned in the 1980s was based. It was called The White Hounds and it was about robot dogs who guarded a city and who were meant to be mere machines, but actually had secret private lives. I may have it on a tape somewhere, in which case it may well have the name of the original story in the blurb for the song, but I moved house recently so I'll have to do some hunting to find my old tapes.

Answer (score -4):

Perhaps the [Neo Dogs](http://starshiptroopers.wikia.com/wiki/Pathfinder_Neodog) mentioned in Robert Heinlein's [Starship Troopers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troopers#Books) books?

If my memory serves me correctly, the Neo Dog (which was referred to as a Caleb) was permanently bonded to a human in the K9 Corps.  If the human in this pair died, the Neo dog was automatically euthanized.  If the Neo-dog died, the human had to be hospitalized to recover from the rupture in the bond.

They were mentioned in the [first book](http://www.technovelgy.com/ct/content.asp?Bnum=2075) of the trilogy;

> "They talk. You simply have to train your ear to their accent. Their
>   mouths can't shape 'b', 'm', 'p', or 'v' and you have to get used to
>   their equivalents...their speech is as clear as any human speech. But
>   a neodog is not a talking dog; he is not a dog at all, he is an
>   artificially mutated symbiote derived from dog stock. A neo...is about
>   six times as bright as a dog, say about as intelligent as a human
>   moron..."
>
> "...Can you imagine being married to a Caleb?"
>
> "Huh? No. No, I can't."
>
> "The emotional relationship between the dog-man and the man-dog in the
>   K-9 team is a great deal closer and much more important than is the
>   emotional relationship in most marriages."

Comment: What "trilogy"? *Starship Troopers* is a standalone novel by R. A. Heinlein. (I hear it's been made into a movie. A shorter version "Starship Soldier" ran as a two-part serial in *F&SF*.) Are you mixing it up with Stasheff's [*Starship Troupers*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Starship_Troupers)?

Comment: He may be referring to the games (looks like there've been four of them), which is where the Calebs show up. That said, I doubt this would match up to the question.

Comment: Calebs were not robotic.

Comment: @Leilani Wilson: Not even close.